# I didn't find any option for Email/Password (firebase-auth)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-authentication, firebase-assistant

[Firebase Auth - Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuWrg.png)

[Firebase Auth - Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD5nl.png)

I want to make a login system with *email and password*. I enabled it from Firebase Website, but when I came to the android studio there is no option to connect with Email/Password.

Image included in the first two links

I read a blog post there he has it like : [Firebase Auth system image from Blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvo2i.png)

Please help if you can.
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

In the first Image simply click on "authenticate using google sign-in" if you are using Java or the one below if you are using Kotlin, you should get:

[image]

Now follow the instructions:

1. test the connection
2. add the SDK

Now you should have access to all the methods you need to interact with Firebase.