# Email and Password Authentication is not visible on Android Studio's

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-assistant

As you can see in the picture, the Firebase tool does not display email and password authentication option. Where can I enable it?

[image]

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68566859/i-didnt-find-any-option-for-email-password-firebase-auth?

Answer (score 0):

It is the option number 5 "using a custom "